# I'm making good progress... & My friends say my pronunciation is much better

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

Please read below text. Could you say why it's necessary to use "I'm making" & "My friends say" in this context, but not "I make" & "My friends are saying"?

> I’m taking the opportunity to improve my English. ***I make*** good progress, I think. ***My friends are saying*** my pronunciation is much better than I arrived...

I thought that it's necessary to use "I make", because it's a fact or my opinion. --> Present Simple.

I thought that it's necessary to use "My friends are saying", because it's an action around now. --> Present Continuous.

Where are mistakes in my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“progress” is inherently something that happens over time, so the simple present doesn’t work unless you add something to show it’s continuous:

- I make progress every day.

Without that, you have to use a continuous verb:

- I am making progress.

“saying” has the opposite problem: it is continuous when presumably you mean a series of separate events:

- My friends say ...

The exception to this is when there are so many people saying the same thing that it becomes continuous:

- Everyone is saying ...

Consider the difference between these statements:

- The bird chirps.
- Birds are chirping.

Comment: I don't understand to the full extent about "My friends say..."

Comment: The bird chirps, as I understand, it means that every bird chirps like every man says something, isn't it?

Comment: "Birds are chirping" it means that some birds are chirping now. Right?

Comment: "Everyone is saying..." is like a template for a sentence. For example, "Everyone is saying that the sky is blue." Am I right?

Comment: But what about "My friends say..."? Why is necessary to use the Present Simple?